# How to develop Custom Camera in android with flash,grid,rotate options

Tags: android

Hello Every body i am trying to develop a custom camera with all customized features like flash, camera rotation, grid ,zoom in and zoom out . Can any body suggest me a good example for all this functionality including thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the API tutorial, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: Hello Mega Mind ,Thanks but i tried to develop that code but my control is not going inside picture call back method after calling  camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, jPictureCallback);..I would be glad if you share some relative examples .

Comment: Sorry, dude. I didn't encounter like that. When I google it, there are many possibility.